# Why does the client not accept my WebSocket response handshake?

Tags: html, google-chrome, websocket

I use Chrome 14. This is my python websocket server code snippet:

```
                    global guid
                    key = hashlib.sha1(headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key']+guid).digest()
                    key.encode('iso-')
                    headers['Sec-WebSotycket-Accept'] = base64.b64encode(key)
                    print headers['Sec-WebSocket-Accept']
                    handshake = '\
    HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n\
    Upgrade: %s\r\
    Connection: %s\r\
    Sec-WebSocket-Accept: %s\r\
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: base64\r\
     ' %(headers['Upgrade'],headers['Connection'],headers['Sec-WebSocket-Accept'])
                    try:
                        self.conn.send(handshake)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print e
```

Why does the Chrome client not accept this server send handshake?

```
Request URL:ws://127.0.0.1:1234/

Request Headers

Connection:Upgrade
Host:127.0.0.1:1234
Sec-WebSocket-Key:xuV2xuiXxqL4Hwcxjg9dJA==
Sec-WebSocket-Origin:null
Sec-WebSocket-Version:8
Upgrade:websocket
(Key3):00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post the request that Chrome made? (Have a look at chrome://net-internals/ -> Sockets -> View live sockets -> select your websocket. Make sure to select the checkbox on the right in the Data tab first.)

Comment: Or could you perhaps send a request key and the response key you're sending?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be line 4 of your server code?  Your key "Sec-WebSotycket-Accept" looks misspelled.